# Proving whether or not a function is regulated

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, trigonometry

Let $\phi : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be a step function and $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be defined $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=sin(1/x)$, $x \in (0,1]$. We want to prove that f is not regulated.

To start I know to choose $\epsilon$ = $1$ but I'm not sure where to go from here without picking a specific step function to start from but that is obviously the wrong way to go about it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of this proof is to note that, since $\phi$ is a step function, in particular it is constant on an interval $[0,a]$ for some $a<1$.

However, the function $f$ will reach both $-1$ and $1$ in $(0,a]$ so there is $x\in[0,a]\subseteq[0,1]$ s.t. $\vert f(x)-\phi(x)\vert\geq 1$. This shows that, for any sequence of step functions $\phi_n$, $\Vert \phi_n-f\Vert_\infty\geq1$, which implies $f$ is not regulated

Comment: The intent of the exercise is to prepare you for the characterization of regulated functions as the class of functions with right- and left-hand limits at every point.  When you see such an exercise try to train yourself to ponder the question: "Hmmm, I wonder what the regulated functions really are?"  If you treat the exercise as a dead-end you are learning about mathematics, but not training yourself to $do$ mathematics.  To become a  mathematician you have to trick your mind into thinking in this weird way.  Generalize every problem if you can!

Comment: Is there any reason we choose $\epsilon$ to be $1$? What if I choose it to be $0.5$?

Comment: Okay, I think I got it. Since the negation of the definition of regulated functions is as follow:

$f$ is not regulated if $\forall \phi \in S[a,b] \text{ there exists } \epsilon : ||f-\phi||_{\infty} \gt \epsilon$

So this means that we need only $1$ (which in our case is $=1$) epsilon to show that for any sequence of step functions, the condition $||f- \phi|| \gt \epsilon$ is met?

Comment: @ThePoorJew Sorry to be pedantic, but I'm afraid, the negation of the property "$\forall \phi \in S[a,b]$, there is $\epsilon : ||f-\phi||_{\infty} > \epsilon$" is "there is $\phi \in S[a,b]$, s.t. $\forall \epsilon : ||f-\phi||_{\infty} \le \epsilon$", which is to say, $f \in S[a,b]$. I assume you actually wanted to say, "$f$ is not regulated if there is $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $\forall f \in S[a,b], ||f-\phi||_{\infty} > \epsilon$", which is the negation of the definition of regulated function. In this case, you only need to prove it for one $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Besides, if you prove it for a specific $\epsilon > 0$, it will be true for all smaller positive values as well