# Proving that sin$(1/x)$ is not regulated

Tags: real-analysis, step-function

I have seen in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1485577/proving-whether-or-not-a-function-is-regulated) howto prove whether sin$(1/x)$ is not regulated. But i'm not quite sure why it's correct. Since the definition of a regulated function is as follows:

[image]

This means that the negation of this definition is:

$f$ is not regulated if $\forall \phi \in S[a,b] \text{ there exists } \epsilon : ||f-\phi||_{\infty} \gt \epsilon$

But the answer in the question above gives that $\epsilon=1$. How are we sure that for any sequence of step functions, the condition $||f-\phi||_{\infty} \gt \epsilon$ is met? I mean isn't the condition met only when sin$(1/x)$ is equal to $1$ (or $-1$) and $\phi(x)=0$? What if I choose a step function that does not equal $0$ ever? Then how is the absolute difference going to be bigger or equal to $1$?

Comment: Just to clarify, a step function in this case has to consist of finitely many "steps", right?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur yes

Comment: @Keen-ameteur is my negation of the definition correct?

Comment: I think that it is true. But in this case you can take $\epsilon=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the idea is that you have sequences of points $\{x_n \}$, $\{ y_n\}$ in $[0,1]$ such that $x_n,y_n\rightarrow 0$, $f(x_n)\equiv 1$ and $f(y_n)\equiv-1$. In particular for any step function $\phi$, has to be equal to some constant $c$ on some interval $(0,\delta)$. In particular:

$$ \Vert f-\phi \Vert_\infty\geq \begin{cases} \vert c-f(x_n) \vert & c\leq0 \\ \vert c-f(y_n) \vert & c>0 \end{cases}\geq 1 $$

I think this proof shows in general that you can't approximate a function with an essential discontinuity point by steps functions uniformly.

Comment: I don't get why you introduce the sequence of points, and why $f(x_n) \equiv 1$

Comment: Take $x_n=\big( \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n \big)^{-1}$. The fact that you have a sequence of points satisfying $x_n\rightarrow 0$, means that for all $\delta>0$ there exists $n$ such that $x_n\in (0,\delta)$.

Comment: Okay, but where does this need for introducing a sequence come from? I mean all we're proving is why $xcos(1/x)$ is regulated? How come now we're dealing with sequences?

Comment: I want to ensure that there is a point  $z\in(0,\delta)$ such that $\vert c-f(z)\vert\geq 1$ for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Iknow of a sequence where $f(x_n)\equiv 1$ and a sequence where $f(y_n)\equiv 1$, and so want to choose $z$ to be $x_n$ or $y_n$ appropriately.

Comment: Ok thanks, i understand now. One last question if you don't mind. Why do the sequences need to converge to $0$?

Comment: Otherwise we won't be sure that there exists $x_n\in(0,\delta)$ and $y_n\in(0,\delta)$.